# Powershell regex match beginning

Tags: regex, powershell, registry, caret

I am trying to get all registry keys beginning with a digit 1-9. This is what I am working with:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Citrix | Where-Object {$_.name -Match '^[1-9]'}
```

Simple huh? Should work? Doesn't work! What am I missing?

Update1:

```powershell
$CitrixPolRegDel = (Get-ChildItem -Path $CitrixPolRegPath).pschildName | Where-Object {$_ -Match '^[0-9]{1,2}$'}
```

This is what I am using now, pschildname turned out to be easier to use than the split example given below, but there might be drawbacks to this method that I am not aware of?

I also updated the regex expression to match regkeys named with one or two digits:

**Regex retreives regkeys where name starts with (`^`) a digit 0-9 (`[0-9]`), digit in name can occur one to two times (`{1,2}`) and then the name should end (`$`)**

Comment: Could you please describe what is the result? as in how it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the funny thing is that you run that GCI and it kicks back a table with the name of the sub keys and that's it, but if you do a Select -Expand Name it gives the full HKLM\Software\Policies\Citrix. So there's the problem, Name actually contains the full name of the key, not just the last sub-key.

So, you want the subkeys that start with 1-9? Split it out by `\` and just use the last one for each entry. Try this out:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Citrix).Name | ForEach {$_.Split("\")[4] | Where-Object {$_.name -Match '^[1-9]'}}
```

Comment: Yes! It works, thank you!  Had to make a slight edit thou.  I removed the .name in the Where-Object section(Where-Object {$_ -Match '^[1-9]'})